# How to collapsed nav-treeview when I click the submenu in AdminLTE 3.0?

Tags: javascript, php, adminlte

As you can see in the GIF when I click the submenu it no longer collapses. What I want is when I click the submenu it will collapse and will not automatically close when I click the page

```html
<li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link <?= $page == 'patients.php' || $page == 'medical_history.php'? 'active':''?>">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-users-medical"></i>
              <p>Patients</p>
              <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview <?= $page == 'patients.php' || $page == 'medical_history.php' ? 'show':''?>">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="patients.php" class="nav-link <?= $page == 'patients.php' ? 'active':''?>">
                  <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Patient List</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="medical_history.php" class="nav-link <?= $page == 'medical_history.php' ? 'active':''?>">
                  <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Medical History</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated...***

I've updated and provided the code you need... just copy and paste this code in the relevant section of your file. I'm sure this will work for you : )

```html
<li class="nav-item <?= $page == 'patients.php' || $page == 'medical_history.php' ? 'menu-open' : '' ?>">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link <?= $page == 'patients.php' || $page == 'medical_history.php' ? 'active' : '' ?>">
    <i class="nav-icon fa fa-users-medical"></i>
    <p>Patients</p>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="patients.php" class="nav-link <?= $page == 'patients.php' ? 'active' : '' ?>">
        <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
        <p>Patient List</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="medical_history.php" class="nav-link <?= $page == 'medical_history.php' ? 'active' : '' ?>">
        <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
        <p>Medical History</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

[image: adminlte-screenshot]

Comment: this is my reference https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/index3.html

Comment: Alright, I got it. Here is what you've to do... Add a `menu-open` class in the `li` element right after the `nav-item` class (which is the first line of your example code).

Comment: Yup, it works, but when I open the dashboard as an example it's not closing

Comment: I think we need to use some javascript here? I guess

Comment: No need for `js` you can do it with PHP script. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70202621/15639663) is what you want : )

Comment: Warm Welcome... Congrats : )

Answer (score 0):

If your AdminLTE template uses **bootstrap**, then try to add a `collapse` and a `show` class in the nested `ul` element right after the `nav-treeview` class.

Comment: do you have any sample code, adding collapsed in nav link class is not working

Comment: There is a difference b/w the `collapse` and `collapsed` classes. You've to add two classes `collapse` and `show` in the `ul` element and try it by removing your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display: none`

```
<ul class="nav nav-treeview" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).